# Consume ActiveMQ advisory messages in tomEE mdb

Tags: activemq-classic, message-driven-bean, apache-tomee

I have an MDB that manages to consume ActiveMQ advisory messages when deployed on glassfish.

But when i deploy on tomEE this MDB doesnt consume any advisory messages. Is there something I need to turn on?

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue", activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.User.*") })
public class AdvisoryMdb implements MessageListener {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        logger.info("onMessage() {}", message);
    }
}
```

(In TomEE I manage to successfully produce and consume messages on these queues i want to advisories for)

edit: i tested to consume on one of these advisory topics with a standalone client and got the messages as expected. So the advisory messages are successfully sent, just that my mdb doesnt pick them up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance i attempted to remove

```
mappedName = "ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue"
```

from the @MessageDriven annotation and suddenly it works on both TomEE and glassfish. Not sure why I added that in the first place, guess it was not needed for glassfish either.

Answer (score 1):

What Advisory messages are you trying to consume?

Taking a look at the documentation [here](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html)... I see `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue` is listed meaning as *Consumer start & stop messages on a Queue*. Your target is `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.User.*`, So do you have a queue called `User`? Is this a single queue or are there multiple queues underneath `User`?

Also reading the doc, there seems to be some changes over the years of the Advisory queue names. Can you check the ActiveMQ versions across the platforms and make sure you're comparing apples to apples? Also, on the documentation page I listed, I kind of wonder if some of the advisories are disabled. It doesn't list that particular queue as one that *can* be disabled, but you might try explicitly enabling all advisories and see if that helps.

Comment: listening on ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.User.* means it will pick up the consumer events on queues matching pattern "User.*"